# Error attempting to remove item from std::stack

Tags: c++, stack, std

When I try to delete one element from a `Vector<Stack<HWND>>`

```
v[index].pop(DestroyWindow(hwnd));
```

I get the error

> Error C2660:: function does not take 1 arguments

It may be necessary to cause the data type?

Comment: Also, the issue isn't with the Windows API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [`std::stack::pop`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/) does not take any arguments (and therefore does not take 1 argument, [`BOOL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) in this case, as the error indicates).  Instead, you should `DestroyWindow(v[index].top())`, then `pop`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for stuped qustion.